# Running jquery funtion over php mysql while loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css

The main aim is to display the row when the master row is clicked, there will be multiple records for one single incident id. how to apply jquery function for this type of output. Helps appreciated.

I tried using jexpand function but its not working.

The main aim is to get output like, when one particular row is clicked the remaining set of row with same id should be expanded and vice-versa.

The table results are fetched from mysql database.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
            body { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-size:0.8em;}
            #report { border-collapse:collapse;}
            #report h4 { margin:0px; padding:0px;}
            #report img { float:right;}
            #report ul { margin:10px 0 10px 40px; padding:0px;}
            #report th { background:#7CB8E2 url(header_bkg.png) repeat-x scroll center left; color:#fff; padding:7px 15px; text-align:left;}
            #childALL { background:#C7DDEE none repeat-x scroll center left; color:#000; padding:7px 15px; }
            #report tr.td { background:#fff url(row_bkg.png) repeat-x scroll center left; cursor:pointer; }
            #report div.arrow { background:transparent url(arrows.png) no-repeat scroll 0px -16px; width:16px; height:16px; display:block;}
            #report div.up { background-position:0px 0px;}
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#report tr:siblings").show();
                $("#report tr:siblings").hide();
                $("#report div.arrow").click(function(){
                    $(this).next("#childALL").toggle();
                    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
                });
                //$("#report").jExpand();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <center>
        <img src="abc.jpg" width="400px" height="100px" />
    </center>

    <?php
        $con=  mysqli_connect("172.28.212.145", "root", "root", "xxx");

        if(!$con)
        {
            die('not connected');
        }

        $con=  mysqli_query($con, "Select Incident_id,name,qualification from masterdata;");
       ?>
    <div>
        <center>
            <table id="report">
                <tr>
                    <th>Incident Id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>Qualification</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $incident = null;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con))
                {
                    if( $row['Incident_id'] != $incident )
                    {   
                        $incident = $row['Incident_id'];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Incident_id']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['JournalUdpdateChanges']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
                </tr>

                <?php } else { ?>

                <tr id="childALL">
                    <td >
                        <?php echo $row['Incident_id']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <?php echo $row['qualification']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <?php echo $row['Priority_im']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr> 
                <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap makes really easy work out of this.

[Bootstrap Accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#accordion)

Comment: Can this be applied for table row and columns?.